# Any idea why the state doesn't seem to be updating in my React ocmponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several React components getting parameters from other components. I am at the last level child, but for some reason, no matter how I declare the setState parameters, the account value state in the component doesn't seem to be updating, which is a basic feature of React. Also, if I try to initialize the state by passing in props from the parent component, the value becomes undefined, yet if I do the same thing in my render function, everything works normally. Here is the code

```
export class AccountValue extends React.Component<ILiquidiManagerProps, AccountState> {
    public constructor(props:ILiquidiManagerProps){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Value: this.props.value,
            Subtotal: this.props.subtotal,
            items: [],
            Date: this.props.date,
            Dates: this.props.dates,        
        }
    }


    private handleChange = e => {
        let value = 0;
        let input = e.target.textContent.replace(/[,.]/g, x => { return x == "," ? "." : ""; });
        if (input && !isNaN(input)) {
            value = parseFloat(input);
        } else {
            value = 0;
        }
        let newTotal = Math.round(value);
        this.setState({
            Value: newTotal
        });
    }

    private keyPress = e => {
        if(e.charCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.target.blur();
          }
    }

    public async componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            Subtotal: this.props.subtotal,
            Value: this.props.value,
        });
    }

    public async componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState){
        if (this.state.Subtotal !== prevState.Subtotal){
            this.props.getValue(this.state.Subtotal);

        }
        if (this.state.Value !== prevState.Value){
            // this.setState({Value: this.props.value,})
            let newSubtotal = this.state.Subtotal - prevState.Value + this.state.Value;
            this.props.getValue(newSubtotal);
        }
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<ILiquidiManagerProps> {
        return(
            <div contentEditable 
                className="bg-white text-right pr-2" 
                data-date={this.props.date}
                data-label={this.props.label}
                onBlur={this.handleChange}
                onKeyPress={this.keyPress}>{this.props.value.toString().replace('.', ',').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: do you expect `Value` to be updated where? when you do `this.props.getValue(this.state.Subtotal)`?

Comment: I am getting 0, even though I am passing the value in from another component

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the spread operator `...` to call the previous state value. For the example in:

```
public async componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            Subtotal: this.props.subtotal,
            Value: this.props.value,
        });
    }
```

You need to call the previous state value every time you want to set a state like this:

```
this.setState({ 
  ...this.state,
  Subtotal: this.props.subtotal,
  Value: this.props.value,
});
```